# Successor in a floating point system

Tags: floating-point, numeric-precision

I’m starting at numerical methods and I am introducing to the machine epsilon and succesor. I have this question, which is the succesor of .13579x10^2 at a floating point system of (10,5,-2,6). My intuiton is that it must be $.1358x10^2$,but then, I know that $.13579x10^2 + \epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is the roundoff unit or machine epsilon. Can someone explain to me better this notion of machine epsilon. Also, I don’t know how to interpretate the operation $.12345-.00001$ at the same system, because $.00001<0.0001=\epsilon$. Then, there shouldn’t be any change. Thanks for the help

Comment: You didn't introduce your (a, b, c, d) tuple. What is its meaning? Cite your reference. For example, 754 single precision described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_and_interchange_formats) could be (2, 24, 8, 127), which doesn't appear to align with the OP. Also, what bit pattern or sequence of (unsigned?) integers are you using to represent FP quantities in this approach? Do you e.g. admit of subnormals? (Which seems relevant when talking about quantities near 1e-4 or 1e-5.) FP questions often become easier when you think of x as representing an interval near x.

Comment: Sorry, my tuple es (b,p,L,U) where b is the base, p is precision, L and U are the range of the exponent of the base

Comment: Ok. So it sounds like a FP quantity is a 6-tuple: five unsigned integers in the range 0 .. 9 inclusive, and an integer exponent in the range -2 .. 6 inclusive. Good. You did not tackle the topic of subnormals, so I shall assume they are forbidden, which simplifies matters -- first digit shall be non-zero if any are non-zero. You mentioned the quantity 1e-5. But you don't get to talk about that quantity, since you just told me that 1e-2 is the smallest above zero that we can represent in this scheme. (I invited you to cite a reference, maybe an URL. You can still do that.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which is the succesor of .13579x10^2 at a floating point system of (10,5,-2,6). My intuiton is that it must be $.1358x10^2$

Your intuition is correct. The successor of .13579x10^2 is .13580x10^2 under the floating point system that you specified.

> Can someone explain to me better this notion of machine epsilon

There are two definitions in use for the machine epsilon, but they have one thing in common: The machine epsilon is defined in relation to the number 1.

The formal definition of epsilon is that it is the largest number you can add to 1, where the result will still be rounded to 1.

A common alternative definition is that it is the difference between 1 and its successor. This alternative definition typically results in a value that is twice as large as when you use the formal definition.

If you calculate the machine epsilon according to the second definition, then the successors are always $\epsilon * exponent$ apart.

Answer (score -1):

Just write down your floating point number in binary, find the value of the first and the last mantissa bit, and you find the number with the next higher absolute value by increasing the mantissa by 1.

If your number is negative then you get the next larger number by decreasing the mantissa. In that case, if your mantissa is all bits zero except for the leading bit, the next number would have a smaller exponent and you can subtract 1/2 of the current mantissa bit.